# Delphi Chromium 3 - CefSingleProcess

Tags: delphi, chromium, tchromium

Having very strange issue with Delphi Chromium 3:

When running the vanilla demo app, (GuiClient), if I separately try to open a Microsoft Excel 2010 file (just double clicking on a file in Explorer,) it takes *significantly* longer than if the Chrome demo is not open. OS is Windows 7.

I have traced this to the "CefSingleProcess := false" line. If this line is commented out, everything works fine. I understand from the DCEF3 developer that Chrome can "run in more than one process" but I am not sure how this could affect the file system.

Even if this is not a fixable issue, I would be very curious to understand what is happening here. :)

Comment: Is this something you observe only with Excel, or does it happen with other programs, too?

Comment: Excellent question - it is apparently just happening with Excel.